# db2 cannot restore from mounted directory?

Tags: linux, mount, db2

`db2 restore db databaseName from Directory` doesn't work (hangs there and does nothing, no error, no time out) for me if the Directory is a nfs mounted directory. Any idea how to make it work?

- db2 v 9.7
- mounted from / to SuSe

## Update I

`db2 restore database RATIONAL from /var/lib/edumate/backup2/ TAKEN AT 20110523123431 into RATIO33` When I restore from NOT mounted it takes about 1-2 minutes to successfully restore the same database.

the restore command never finishes. I mean it won't give me command line prompt back. But the log file....

```
2011-06-06-12.06.24.567599+600 E4116E482           LEVEL: Info
PID     : 1125                 TID  : 140594982676224PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000          DB   : RATIO33
APPHDL  : 0-18                 APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.110606020625
AUTHID  : DB2INST1
EDUID   : 286                  EDUNAME: db2agent (RATIO33)
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqluxGetDegreeParallelism, probe:816
DATA #1 : <preformatted>
Autonomic BAR - using parallelism = 2.

2011-06-06-12.08.18.594032+600 I4599E427           LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 1125                 TID  : 140597138548480PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
APPHDL  : 0-19                 APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.110606020818
AUTHID  : DB2INST1
EDUID   : 26                   EDUNAME: db2agent (instance)
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlb_counts, probe:90
MESSAGE : max pool id is less than 0 at -1

2011-06-06-12.08.18.599571+600 E5027E638           LEVEL: Error
PID     : 1144                 TID  : 140584019629840PROC : db2acd
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, Health Monitor, HealthIndicator::update, probe:500
MESSAGE : ADM10500E  Health indicator "Database Heap Utilization" 
          ("db.db_heap_util") breached the "upper" alarm threshold of "95 %" 
          with value "101 %" on "database" "db2inst1.RATIO33 ".  Calculation: 
          "((db.db_heap_cur_size/db.db_heap_max_size)*100);" = "((31981568 / 
          31522816) * 100)" = "101 %".  History (Timestamp, Value, Formula): 
          "()"

2011-06-06-12.18.18.801386+600 I5666E427           LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 1125                 TID  : 140597138548480PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
APPHDL  : 0-32                 APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.110606021818
AUTHID  : DB2INST1
EDUID   : 26                   EDUNAME: db2agent (instance)
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlb_counts, probe:90
MESSAGE : max pool id is less than 0 at -1

2011-06-06-12.18.22.146592+600 I6094E433           LEVEL: Warning
PID     : 1125                 TID  : 140596941416192PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
EDUID   : 1                    EDUNAME: db2sysc
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, fast comm manager, sqkfDynamicResourceMgr::AdjustResources, probe:100
MESSAGE : FCM Automatic/Dynamic Resource Adjustment (Channel): 1280 will be 
          released; new total will be 3840

2011-06-06-12.28.18.088276+600 I6528E427           LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 1125                 TID  : 140597138548480PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000
APPHDL  : 0-46                 APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.110606022818
AUTHID  : DB2INST1
EDUID   : 26                   EDUNAME: db2agent (instance)
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, buffer pool services, sqlb_counts, probe:90
MESSAGE : max pool id is less than 0 at -1
```

and when I press CTRL+C I get. Interesting is that I don't get my command line prompt back.

```
2011-06-06-12.36.06.245883+600 E7510E922           LEVEL: Severe
PID     : 1125                 TID  : 140594982676224PROC : db2sysc
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000          DB   : RATIO33
APPHDL  : 0-18                 APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.110606020625
AUTHID  : DB2INST1
EDUID   : 286                  EDUNAME: db2agent (RATIO33)
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, database utilities, sqludPollMsg, probe:119
MESSAGE : SQL2001N  The utility was interrupted.  The output data may be 
          incomplete.
DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -2001   sqlerrml: 0
 sqlerrmc: 
 sqlerrp : sqludPol
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x00000000      (2) 0x00000000      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)    
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)     
 sqlstate:
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to look in the db2diag.log? you can find it in the sqllib/db2dump/ directory or by just typing db2diag in command line

Comment: `Update I` added to my question